# Source wanted: Talmudic story of either Tanah or amorah with many children dreading and not enjoying maritial intercource

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, marriage

I heard this story of a Tanah or Amorah who had many children (possibly 11) but it was said he didn't enjoy intercourse with his wife. This was his opinion on how one should approach the subject of intercourse in general. But if I remember correctly the Gemarah called this opinion extreme.

Finding this source is of great interest to me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

BT ([Nedarim 20a-b](https://www.sefaria.org/Nedarim.20b?lang=bi)):

> שאלו את אימא שלום מפני מה בניך יפיפין ביותר אמרה להן אינו מספר עמי לא בתחלת הלילה ולא בסוף הלילה אלא בחצות הלילה וכשהוא מספר מגלה טפח ומכסה טפח ודומה עליו כמי שכפאו שד

Trans. (Sefaria):

> Imma Shalom [the wife of Rabbi Eliezer ben Hyrcanus], was asked: For what reason are your children so beautiful? She said to them: My husband does not converse with me [while engaging in sexual intercourse], neither at the beginning of the night nor at the end of the night, but rather at midnight. And when he converses with me [while engaging in sexual intercourse], he reveals a handbreadth [of my body] and covers a handbreadth, [and he covers himself up] as though he were being coerced by a demon [and is covering himself out of fear.]

Comment: This isn't that similar to the OP's story, IMO. I think the Yerushalmi about R Yosef's Yibbum is arguably more similar.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thats why I initially only posted it as a comment but, in the now deleted comment, OP endorsed the source (perhaps OP misremembered some details).

Comment: please post Yerushalmi source I am very interested in looking at it. This in indeed the source I was looking for as I never learnt Yerushalmi.